# How to insert a new column into a dataframe and access rows with different indices?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with one column "Numbers" and I want to add a second column "Result". The values should be the sum of the previous two values in the "Numbers" column, otherwise NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "Numbers": [100,200,400,0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,index = ["whatever1", "whatever2", "whatever3", "whatever4"])

def add_prev_two_elems_to_DF(df):
    numbers = "Numbers" # alias
    result = "Result"   # alias
    df[result] = np.nan # empty column
    result_index = list(df.columns).index(result)
    for i in range(len(df)):
        #row = df.iloc[i]
        if i < 2: df.iloc[i,result_index] = np.nan
        else: df.iloc[i,result_index] = df.iloc[i-1][numbers] + df.iloc[i-2][numbers]

add_prev_two_elems_to_DF(df)
display(df)
```

The output is:

```
            Numbers Result
whatever1   100     NaN
whatever2   200     NaN
whatever3   400     300.0
whatever4   0       600.0
```

But this looks quite complicated. Can this be done easier and maybe faster? I am not looking for a solution with sum(). I want a general solution for any kind of function that can fill a column using values from other rows.

**Edit 1:** I forgot to import numpy.

**Edit 2:** I changed one line to this:

> if i < 2: df.iloc[i,result_index] = np.nan

Comment: Code and output don't match for the first two rows of "Result" column. What do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the shortest code I could develop. It outputs exactly the same table.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import swifter # apply() gets swifter

data = {
    "Numbers": [100,200,400,0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,index = ["whatever1", "whatever2", "whatever3", "whatever4"])

def func(a: np.ndarray) -> float: # we expect 3 elements, but we don't check that
    a.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True) # the index now starts with 0, 1,...
    return a[0] + a[1] # we use the first two elements, the 3rd is unnecessary

df["Result"] = df["Numbers"].rolling(3).apply(func)
#df["Result"] = df["Numbers"].swifter.rolling(3).apply(func)
display(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use `rolling.sum` together with `shift`. Since `rollling.sum` sums until the current row, we have to shift it down one row, so that each row value matches to the sum of the previous 2 rows:

```
df['Result'] = df['Numbers'].rolling(2).sum().shift()
```

Output:

```
           Numbers  Result
whatever1      100     NaN
whatever2      200     NaN
whatever3      400   300.0
whatever4        0   600.0
```

Comment: No, I am not interested in summing, but in a better technique to make functions of any kind that need to fill cells but also use values from other rows. Summing is only an insignificant example here. I could also have used the square root of 42. And there is no root42().

Comment: @B.A.Sylla you can `apply` any function you like instead of `sum` as long as it's a function that aggregates numbers. The general idea stays the same. If you have a specific function in mind, I can test it for you.

Comment: Post a source code with apply that does exactly what my code does. Is this then simpler, faster or both? I need to see the code to mark it as an answer. I don't think this is possible with apply. How do you access other lines?

Comment: @B.A.Sylla To get the exact output your function produces, you can use `df['Result'] = df['Numbers'].rolling(2).sum().shift().fillna(df['Numbers'])`. It's about 2x faster on my machine. If you have a more complicated function in mind, edit your question to include it, so that I could test if it can be written more efficiently.

Comment: You didn't read my comment above. I'm not interested in sum(). I want a general solution for all imaginable functions. When you say it's possible with apply, then please show the code.

Comment: @B.A.Sylla I did read your comment. My answer is to your intial question (which you edited to be something completely different right now). But as to your current question, it depends on what your goal is. For this specific function, rolling works well, but depending on the context, you have shift, expanding, ewm, cumsum, cumprod, cumcount, cummax, etc.